# C# .NET Core: translate Identity reference SID to display value for Active Directory groups and users

Tags: c#, .net-core, active-directory

I'm switching an API from .NET Framework to .NET Core and running into some differences in the behavior of `Directory.Services.AccountManagement` vs `System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl` in .NET Core 3.1.

The issue in the .NET Core code is I'm trying to get the Active Directory group name (or user name) for each rule for a file. I can get the sid, but the `FileSystemAccessRule.IdentifyReference.Translate()` method throws an exception for AD groups.

Here's what I have: I can get the SID in the `id` variable, but I need the actual group name (or user name)

```
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace ConsoleCoreAclsPoc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fn = args[0];

            var rules = new FileSecurity(fn, AccessControlSections.All | AccessControlSections.Access)
                               .GetAccessRules(true,true,typeof(NTAccount));

            foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in rules)
            {
                FileSystemAccessRule fileRule = rule as FileSystemAccessRule;

                if (fileRule != null)
                {
                    var id = fileRule.IdentityReference;//.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
                    var read = fileRule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute);
                    var write = fileRule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.Modify);
                    var admin = fileRule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.FullControl);

                    if (!admin)
                    {
                        // do stuff to the non-admins
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and found an exception in Access Control Sections. The compiler does not allow access to all security When you want to access the permissions of a file. Change `AccessControlSections` to `AccessControlSections.Access`. Then I did not find any error.

```
var rules = new FileSecurity(fn, AccessControlSections.Access)
             .GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
```